# ERROR: Module mod-evasive does not exist! After installation Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, apache2.4

I installed mod-evasive with

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-evasive
```

under Ubuntu 13.10 after i insert

```
a2enmod mod-evasive
```

into shell i get an error

```
ERROR: Module mod-evasive does not exist!
```

has anyone a suggestion to fix this Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When enabling modules in apache, you don't need to specify the `mod-` prefix.

In this case, to enable the evasive module, you need to use the following command

```
a2enmod evasive
```

Comment: ok this worked for me, thx!